# routeChangeStart is not fired when route changed

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this code snippet below (ionic framework) but `routeChangeStart` is not printed when i'm navigating around.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $location) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    console.info('[event] routeChangeStart...');
  });
})
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I believe that ionic framework is using ui-router instead of ngRoute..So change your code as follows and try...

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  //print here
});
```

please look the following link for the difference between those router modules 
http://www.amasik.com/angularjs-ngroute-vs-ui-router/